# Удалить первое слово если оно начинается с определенного символа

Tags: php

Например есть строка:

```
@test this is text ..... @two this is text
```

Мне нужно чтобы удалялось только первое слово если оно начинается с символа @

То есть в результате должно отстатся:

```
this is text ..... @two this is text
```

буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: strpos str_replace пробовали?  на крайняк preg_replace

Comment: самое первое слово в строке, или первое слово с символом @, не обязательно в начале?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '@test this is text ..... @two this is text';

$atPos = strpos($str, '@');
$spacePos = strpos($str, ' ');
$resultStr = $str;

if ($atPos === 0) {
    $resultStr = substr($str, $spacePos + 1);
} 


echo $resultStr;
```

или

```
$str = '@test this is text ..... @two this is text';

$pattern = '/^(@\w+\s+)/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Comment: речь про первое слово в принципе, а не первое подходящее. В смысле про подходящее, но и первое одновременно. и `\s+` тоже грохнуть, наверное

Comment: Поправил........

Comment: эм, `/^(@\w+\s*)/` то чем не угодили?

Comment: Я не силён в регулярках))

Comment: Вернул регулярку))